# OpenGraph Music music.listens returns error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Following the spec here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/

When I post:
POST https://graph.facebook.com/me/music.listens?song=[song url]

The response is invariably:

{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "An unknown error has occurred."
   }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bug report has been filed here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/124491790988961

According to a developer in the comments section, open graph music is not yet available to the developer public.

Answer (score 1):

A Facebook developer replied regarding this here: 
[Opengraph and music.listen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782255/opengraph-and-music-listen)

Seems like the best option is to create own "play music" actions, since Facebook doesn't seem to allow `POST` to `music.listens` in a foreseeable future... :/

Answer (score 1):

To add on Kristofer and Garthex answers this Built-in Actions is not publicly available. However, you can submit a request if you think you have the rights on content broadcasting.

Here is the doc for Built-in Actions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/

Alternativly, you can use Custom Actions like "A user Play a Sound".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have prompted the user for publish_actions extended permission and that the user is a developer of the application (since the open graph actions are still in beta).

Comment: Check and check ... still no joy.

Here's the interesting thing.  Other developers of the app (who are friended) can see the music posts on my wall ... but without play buttons.  The cover art gets put into the 'Music' section in the timeline overview.  But if you drill into it ... nothing there.