# Getting the "feed" messages of a specific app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed, spotify

I would like to develop an app that recommends music to the user based on the music his/her friends listen to. But in order to do so, I would need a list of the music of the friends of the user. So my question is: is there a way to retrieve the posts made by your friends via Spotify?

Comment: I need this too. Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098539/open-graph-built-in-actions-like-video-watches-or-news-reads-from-my-friends-a

Answer (score 1):

Your app can connect to Facebook and get the user's friends and (I believe) listens using the Facebook API.

The Spotify Apps API does not provide this directly to you.

Comment: I already figured that part out .. But I did not find a way to get this information out of the Facebook API itself. Because the feed doesn't contain Spotify messages..

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is the same as my reply to this question: [OpenGraph Music music.listens returns error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602579/opengraph-music-music-listens-returns-error/10428734#10428734)

Facebook are yet to allow everyone to use `music.listens` freely, both in terms of reading and writing the data.