# Open Graph built-in actions (like video.watches or news.reads) from my friends always empty

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to get all `video.watches` from my friends with

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends/video.watches?access_token=<valid_token>
```

My access token has both `user_actions.video` and `friends_actions.video` permissions.
And I get empty result:

```
{
"data": []
}
```

While a friend of mine with id 100000291284354 has watched videos with Vevo app and when I do

```
https://graph.facebook.com/100000291284354/video.watches?access_token=<valid_token>
```

I get these videos.
The same with `news.reads` (I can get the news if I put the friend id, while get empty result when I request via `/me/friends/`)

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that's the correct action. Or I would want to believe so.

`user_actions.video` should grant `me/video.watches` *only* and `friends_actions.video` should grant `friend_id/video.watches`. A valid way to check would be to drop the `friends_actions.video` permission and try again with the user id you mentioned. But then why is there an end /me/friends/video.watches?

I don't think this endpoint should exist. It seems you can attach `video.watches` path to the end of some graph calls and it will silently fail with an empty an array as opposed to the pagination link you are given

```
{
  "data": [
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "pagination_url"
  }
}
```

Try it yourself (in my case I tried it with music.listens)

- /me/photos/music.listens - *Silently fails with call to /me/photos*
- /me/likes/music.listens - *Error 100*
- /me/friends/music.listens - *Silently fails with empty array*

The rest behave as expected with invalid path components so a second guess would be some of these paths are bugs.

So, I don't think you are able to do, what you think you can do; grab all the activity of your friends all at once.

Comment: phwd is correct. There is not 1 api call to get all the open graph activity from your friends. You have to explicitly make the call for each friend id.

Comment: @JeffSherlock that is not true anymore. See Nils' answer.

Comment: yup, my comment is now outdated. At the time it was correct :)

Answer (score 4):

Facebook has enhanced there API yesterday, try this Graph API request:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?limit=10&fields=name,video.watches.limit(2)
```

see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/
and https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/30/updates-to-the-graph-api/